# How do I grind down #10 galvanized DeckMate Screws?

Tags: screws

I drilled about 50 #10 galvanized Deckmate screws into my new fence before realizing they are too long, and sticking out the back of the 2x4 the fence pickets are drilled to by 1/4 in.

One of the answers in a [similar post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21875/what-kind-of-drill-bit-would-i-use-to-grind-down-the-end-of-a-protruding-screw/22020#22020) suggests using 4 1/2 inch side grinder, "Very carefully."  Would this work in my scenario?  What does "Very Carefully" mean?  Would a 7" grinder be more effective?  Does this method contemplate ruining 50 grinder blades?  Would it be less expensive and/or faster to remove and replace the screws with with shorter #8 screws, or does this significantly compromise the strength of the fence?

UPDATE TO POST

Thank you all very much for the answers and insight.  It never occured to me that #12 2" screws might be found online.  Since the local hardware doesn't sell them, I assumed they didn't exist.  Today I counteed out exactly how many of the shorter #12 screws to order, and  realized the 50 I estimated above is way off; it's more like 250.

My inclination at this point is to cut the ends off with a reciprocating saw as Nate suggests below. Is a specific type of saw blade or technique recommended for cutting nails?

I also failed to recognize the rust problem Nate identified, and wonder if the superhero-ultraviolet-blocking paint sheild that I am double-coating the fence with might prevent the cutoff ends of the screws from rusting?

Comment: At a minimum, replace with shorter #10 screws -- #8s will be loose in the existing hole. Even better would be shorter #12s. (Lots of online sources for obscure screws... McFeelys is one among many.)

Comment: Don't count on it not rusting with the paint you refer to, normally the metal is primed with a suitable primer, then perhaps, finished with the paint you noted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love my multi tool! I use my sawzall attachment with a nail blade and i cut the ends off then with a small punch and hammer just give it a quick wack to push any little overhang back into wood. It won't push screw out. You can use any sawzall. I suggest battery powered so your not fighting a cord which could get cut. Pulling screws out is an option but you will lose the strength of the tightness if you go into the same hole. So I would cut ends.

Comment: My inclination at this point is to cut the ends off with a reciprocating saw as Nate suggests above. Is a specific type of saw blade or technique recommended for cutting nails?

I also failed to recognize the rust problem Nate identified, and wonder if the superhero-ultraviolet-blocking paint sheild that I am double-coating the fence with might prevent the cutoff ends of the screws from rusting?

Answer (score 5):

If it is only 50 screws, pull them out and replace them. Grinding them off would work too, but the ends that were cut would rust, if that makes difference. Besides the hash marks from the grinder may not be so appealing either.

Comment: yep, take them out and replace them.  Actually be quicker and easier